# Symfony2: Need a controller that is executed everytime my baselayout is loaded

Tags: symfony, controller, view

I extend my baselayout in every twig template like

```
{% extends 'someBundle::base.html.twig' %}
```

Now i need some stuff to do on the mainpage and therefor i need a controller that is executed everytime the base.html.twig is loaded, so dont have to do this stuff in every single controller.

I have googled a lot but did not find anything. Don't know exactly what to search for.

I'm sure u know i mean, if not its no problem to explain further. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a very simple [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) which provides a template function, which again you can embed into your `base.html.twig`.

This way, each time `base.html.twig` is loaded, the function is executed. As the Twig extension is basically a special type of service, you can pass it any dependencies you need.

Comment: Hm as far as i see im able to add a global variable with twig extension, or create my own filters or stuff. But what i really wanna do is to pass an object to the base.html.twig template where i can iterate over it as i want. I need to build dynamicly javascript to create markers for a google map from database.

Comment: Ok, that sounds a bit different than what you wrote in the question. Anyway … you can use the Twig extension just like a controller. The function can echo or return any values you want in the template, including arrays over which you want to iterate.